# Angular unidirectional data flow in nested forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm working on an angular app with nested forms. The main page contains the submit button for the entire page and each of the child components (which contain forms) needs to register itself with the parent form in order for validation of the entire page to work properly.

In order to do this I first tried having a `FormArray` in the page component and passing that to the children which then call `formArray.push(this.formGroup)`. This worked properly except for the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` that I got.

Reading about the error I realized that this might be violating the principle of unidirectional data flow since the child updates the parent `formArray`.

I updated the logic instead to have the children emit events containing their own form groups and the page listens to these events and adds the child `formGroups` to the `FormArray`.

Unfortunately this still seems to sometimes cause the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, even though to my understanding the unidirectional data flow is not being violated? It seems now that when the child component is initialized via *ngFor it works properly but directly putting the child component the template (without `ngI` or `ngFor`) causes the exception.

Any ideas on why this might be happening or general approaches to validating all nested forms on a page?

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: Reading your question without code is like explaining to somebody that never heard of software how server-side-rendering works. Maybe put a code snipped under every block of text so that developers can see what you mean, not guess